# what to do with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The program works fine when I export an executable jar to my Windows 10 system, but not in Eclipse.
What have I missed?

Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\openJDK\jdk-19.0.1\bin\gdalalljni.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.HasThreadSupport()'
at org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.HasThreadSupport(Native Method)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.MainDialog.(MainDialog.java:371)

Comment: Make sure `java.library.path` is set to the same value as when running the jar

Answer (score 0):

When you move to Eclipse, the native library is no more in the classpath of your project, that is why you are getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" error. You need to add the native library to the classpath of your eclipse project.

Comment: Please bare with me, I don't understand what to do with DLLs. I have set the path ( C:\openJDK\jdk-19.0.1\bin\, where I have the gdalalljni.dll) in the Eclipse; "Java Build Path" -> "Source tab" ->"Native library location" and also in "Java Build Path" -> "Libraries tab" -> ClassPath-> gdal.jar->"Native library location". But getting the same error code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).